# Hapi FHIR: searching for patient identifier using Postman

Tags: postman, fetch-api, hl7-fhir, hapi, hapi-fhir

I am using Postman to test the connectivity with the Hapi FHIR server and have have been testing different queries but nothing is working...

The expected result is to get all the observations that match a certain patient **identifier** but, at this point, I could only get information by searching for the patient ID.

This is the base query:
`http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/Observation`

I tried lots of different parameters, including:

```
?identifier:of-type={identifier.system OR identifier.type.coding.system}|MR|1234
?patient.identifier=1234 OR {full url from above}
?identifier={full url OR 1234}
?subject=1234
?_has:Observation:patient:identifier=1234
```

and so many others. They either respond with a 500, 400 or a 200OK but with nothing in the Bundle. I checked if I had the patient itself as well as the observations and they are all there, if I search using their ID.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is really a programming questionn, but which patient id are you talking about? Patient.id, or Patient.identifier? Your second option is correct for Patient.identifier, and your fourth option is correct for Patient.id

Comment: I'm talking about Patient.identifier but it is not working :L are you refering to patient.identifier = 1234 (example) or patient.identifier= identifier.system|MR|1234?

Comment: Neither are working, just checking if I'm doing the correct thing

Comment: That first one should definitely work, but: what do you call ‘not working’? Do you get an error message - if so: what does it say? Or do you get an empty Bundle back? - if so, apparently there is no Observation linked to a Patient with identifier 1234.

Comment: I apologize for the delay in the response. With the first one I get a 200 OK with nothing in it, an empty bundle, yes! But I know the patient has observations linked to it because I posted them and if I query for them (using their ID), they appear. The observations have the reference to the subject

Comment: Then you will have to check the reference to see if it says “Patient/[id]” where [id] matches your Patient’s id. From the empty Bundle response, I am certain you have an error in that reference. I use HAPI all the time with similar queries without problems.

Comment: hum, I see. But I need the [patient.identifier]. Using the observation/[ID] gives me back that observation, which has a subject reference to the patient. I need to retrieve ALL observations that have that subject reference, using the [patient.identifier]

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Observation that is correctly linked to a Patient, you can search for the Observations using the Patient's identifier.

My comment was to try and check if the Observation(s) is/are correctly linked to the Patient. So if you have a Patient with technical id 234567 and identifier 1234, does the Observation.subject field show `[base]/Patient/234567`? If so, this search will work on HAPI:

`GET [base]/Observation?patient.identifier=1234`

Also, these searches will work, but they use the technical id instead of the identifier:

`GET [base]/Observation?patient=234567`

`GET [base]/Observation?subject=Patient/234567`

Comment: I verified on Simplifier.net and it showed no errors, all the observations are valid and correctly linked to the patient. 
Yes, the observation.subject has a "reference" field with: Patient/234567 and that query for the identifier still doesn't work...

Comment: Maybe a weird question, but are both the Observations and Patient stored on the HAPI server? - if not, the search is not expected to work; if so, maybe you can give me the technical id of the Patient and one of the linked Observations, so I can check.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by stored on the Hapi server, all I know is that I can search for the patient on their website (hapi.fhir.org/....) and it pops up. Is that it? Unfortunately I am not allowed to provide that but thank you so much anyway!

Comment: I meant that both the Patient and its Observations are persisted on the same system, which would be the HAPI FHIR test server you mentioned in your post. You do realize that it is a PUBLIC server, right? So anyone can see any of the data you store there. I just needed a pointer to the specific resources you used, to be able to help you further. Anyway, try a GET [base]/Observation?patient.identifier=1020304050&code=8310-5, and you will see that the query works on HAPI.