# FHIR: Not finding DiagnosticReport for patient id on SmartHealthIt server

Tags: hl7-fhir

I'm trying to find DiagnosticReport resources for a given patient using the SmartHealthIt R4 server for testing (https://r4.smarthealthit.org).

I've loaded the Patient and DiagnosticReport resources shown below.

The patient has the following for id:

```
 "resourceType": "Patient",
 "id": "1435573",
```

The DiagnosticReport has the following for subject:

```
 "subject": {
    "reference": "Patient/1435573"
  }
```

None of the following searches return this DiagnosticReport.  How do I get all of the DiagnosticReport resources for Patient/1435573 including the one used in this example (I can modify the Patient, the DiagnosticReport, and/or the urls to get the result).  The queries below are based on [Hapi FHIR: searching for patient identifier using Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70023508/hapi-fhir-searching-for-patient-identifier-using-postman).  All of the queries give basically an empty bundle (contains only the self url) except for the last that gives an invalid query error.

Queries:

https://r4.smarthealthit.org/DiagnosticReport?subject=1435573

https://r4.smarthealthit.org/DiagnosticReport?patient.identifier=1435573

https://r4.smarthealthit.org/DiagnosticReport?subject=Patient/1435573

https://r4.smarthealthit.org/DiagnosticReport?subject=https://r4.smarthealthit.org/Patient/1435573

https://r4.smarthealthit.org/DiagnosticReport?subject=http://r4.smarthealthit.org/Patient/1435573

https://r4.smarthealthit.org/DiagnosticReport?subject.reference=1435573
(invalid parameter chain error)

**Full Patient Resource (response from the url shown below):**

https://r4.smarthealthit.org/Patient/1435573

```
{
    "resourceType": "Patient",
    "id": "1435573",
    "meta": {
        "versionId": "1",
        "lastUpdated": "2022-11-20T12:31:20.724-05:00",
        "profile": [
            "http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-patient"
        ]
    },
    "text": {
        "status": "generated",
        "div": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Generated by <a href=\"https://github.com/synthetichealth/synthea\">Synthea</a>.Version identifier: master-branch-latest\n .   Person seed: -3481236467670898486  Population seed: 1663786624475</div>"
    },
    "extension": [
        {
            "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-race",
            "extension": [
                {
                    "url": "ombCategory",
                    "valueCoding": {
                        "system": "urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.6.238",
                        "code": "2106-3",
                        "display": "White"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "url": "text",
                    "valueString": "White"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-ethnicity",
            "extension": [
                {
                    "url": "ombCategory",
                    "valueCoding": {
                        "system": "urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.6.238",
                        "code": "2186-5",
                        "display": "Not Hispanic or Latino"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "url": "text",
                    "valueString": "Not Hispanic or Latino"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/patient-mothersMaidenName",
            "valueString": "Natosha194 Rolfson709"
        },
        {
            "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-birthsex",
            "valueCode": "M"
        },
        {
            "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/patient-birthPlace",
            "valueAddress": {
                "city": "Westfield",
                "state": "Massachusetts",
                "country": "US"
            }
        },
        {
            "url": "http://synthetichealth.github.io/synthea/disability-adjusted-life-years",
            "valueDecimal": 0.011850126818590398
        },
        {
            "url": "http://synthetichealth.github.io/synthea/quality-adjusted-life-years",
            "valueDecimal": 30.98814987318141
        }
    ],
    "identifier": [
        {
            "system": "https://github.com/synthetichealth/synthea",
            "value": "d7e5852a-974c-6d45-f81d-5a87bbd05d2a"
        },
        {
            "type": {
                "coding": [
                    {
                        "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
                        "code": "MR",
                        "display": "Medical Record Number"
                    }
                ],
                "text": "Medical Record Number"
            },
            "system": "http://hospital.smarthealthit.org",
            "value": "d7e5852a-974c-6d45-f81d-5a87bbd05d2a"
        },
        {
            "type": {
                "coding": [
                    {
                        "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
                        "code": "SS",
                        "display": "Social Security Number"
                    }
                ],
                "text": "Social Security Number"
            },
            "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/sid/us-ssn",
            "value": "999-55-2948"
        },
        {
            "type": {
                "coding": [
                    {
                        "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
                        "code": "DL",
                        "display": "Driver's License"
                    }
                ],
                "text": "Driver's License"
            },
            "system": "urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.4.3.25",
            "value": "S99934182"
        },
        {
            "type": {
                "coding": [
                    {
                        "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
                        "code": "PPN",
                        "display": "Passport Number"
                    }
                ],
                "text": "Passport Number"
            },
            "system": "http://standardhealthrecord.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/passportNumber",
            "value": "X1908681X"
        }
    ],
    "name": [
        {
            "use": "official",
            "family": "Hermiston71",
            "given": [
                "Glenn0",
                "Adalberto916"
            ],
            "prefix": [
                "Mr."
            ]
        }
    ],
    "telecom": [
        {
            "system": "phone",
            "value": "555-370-8941",
            "use": "home"
        }
    ],
    "gender": "male",
    "birthDate": "1960-07-09",
    "deceasedDateTime": "1992-06-21T18:48:35-04:00",
    "address": [
        {
            "extension": [
                {
                    "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/geolocation",
                    "extension": [
                        {
                            "url": "latitude",
                            "valueDecimal": 42.1419070399434
                        },
                        {
                            "url": "longitude",
                            "valueDecimal": -71.28041093915812
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "line": [
                "236 Halvorson Mews Suite 21"
            ],
            "city": "Walpole",
            "state": "MA",
            "country": "US"
        }
    ],
    "maritalStatus": {
        "coding": [
            {
                "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v3-MaritalStatus",
                "code": "M",
                "display": "M"
            }
        ],
        "text": "M"
    },
    "multipleBirthBoolean": false,
    "communication": [
        {
            "language": {
                "coding": [
                    {
                        "system": "urn:ietf:bcp:47",
                        "code": "en-US",
                        "display": "English"
                    }
                ],
                "text": "English"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Full DiagnosticReport Resource (response from the url shown below):**

https://r4.smarthealthit.org/DiagnosticReport/1435574

```
{
    "resourceType": "DiagnosticReport",
    "id": "1435574",
    "meta": {
        "versionId": "1",
        "lastUpdated": "2022-11-20T12:36:53.205-05:00",
        "profile": [
            "http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-diagnosticreport-note"
        ]
    },
    "status": "final",
    "category": [
        {
            "coding": [
                {
                    "system": "http://loinc.org",
                    "code": "34117-2",
                    "display": "History and physical note"
                },
                {
                    "system": "http://loinc.org",
                    "code": "51847-2",
                    "display": "Evaluation + Plan note"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "code": {
        "coding": [
            {
                "system": "http://loinc.org",
                "code": "34117-2",
                "display": "History and physical note"
            },
            {
                "system": "http://loinc.org",
                "code": "51847-2",
                "display": "Evaluation + Plan note"
            }
        ]
    },
    "subject": {
        "reference": "Patient/1435573"
    },
    "effectiveDateTime": "1978-09-02T17:57:46-04:00",
    "issued": "1978-09-02T17:57:46.296-04:00",
    "performer": [
        {
            "display": "Dr. Debbie941 Macejkovic424"
        }
    ],
    "presentedForm": [
        {
            "contentType": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
            "data": "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"
        }
    ]
}
```

--- EDIT ---------------------------------------

This query (suggested in answer below) also does not work.  Screen shots are for a newly create patient (the original was deleted).

https://r4.smarthealthit.org/DiagnosticReport?patient=1437050

[image]

[image]

[image]

--- EDIT: STEPS TO REPRODUCE ---------------------------------

It looks like the patients created by end users are routinely deleted from this server (which makes sense).  Here are the steps to reproduce the issue.

POST this messge to https://launch.smarthealthit.org/v/r4/fhir/Patient

```
{
  "identifier": [
    {
      "system": "https://github.com/synthetichealth/synthea",
      "value": "d7e5852a-974c-6d45-f81d-5a87bbd05d2a"
    },
    {
      "system": "http://hospital.smarthealthit.org",
      "type": {
        "coding": [{
          "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
          "code": "MR",
          "display": "Medical Record Number"
        }],
        "text": "Medical Record Number"
      },
      "value": "d7e5852a-974c-6d45-f81d-5a87bbd05d2a"
    },
    {
      "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/sid/us-ssn",
      "type": {
        "coding": [{
          "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
          "code": "SS",
          "display": "Social Security Number"
        }],
        "text": "Social Security Number"
      },
      "value": "999-55-2948"
    },
    {
      "system": "urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.4.3.25",
      "type": {
        "coding": [{
          "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
          "code": "DL",
          "display": "Driver's License"
        }],
        "text": "Driver's License"
      },
      "value": "S99934182"
    },
    {
      "system": "http://standardhealthrecord.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/passportNumber",
      "type": {
        "coding": [{
          "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v2-0203",
          "code": "PPN",
          "display": "Passport Number"
        }],
        "text": "Passport Number"
      },
      "value": "X1908681X"
    }
  ],
  "extension": [
    {
      "extension": [
        {
          "valueCoding": {
            "system": "urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.6.238",
            "code": "2106-3",
            "display": "White"
          },
          "url": "ombCategory"
        },
        {
          "valueString": "White",
          "url": "text"
        }
      ],
      "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-race"
    },
    {
      "extension": [
        {
          "valueCoding": {
            "system": "urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.6.238",
            "code": "2186-5",
            "display": "Not Hispanic or Latino"
          },
          "url": "ombCategory"
        },
        {
          "valueString": "Not Hispanic or Latino",
          "url": "text"
        }
      ],
      "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-ethnicity"
    },
    {
      "valueString": "Natosha194 Rolfson709",
      "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/patient-mothersMaidenName"
    },
    {
      "valueCode": "M",
      "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-birthsex"
    },
    {
      "valueAddress": {
        "country": "US",
        "city": "Westfield",
        "state": "Massachusetts"
      },
      "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/patient-birthPlace"
    },
    {
      "valueDecimal": 0.011850126818590398,
      "url": "http://synthetichealth.github.io/synthea/disability-adjusted-life-years"
    },
    {
      "valueDecimal": 30.98814987318141,
      "url": "http://synthetichealth.github.io/synthea/quality-adjusted-life-years"
    }
  ],
  "address": [{
    "country": "US",
    "extension": [{
      "extension": [
        {
          "valueDecimal": 42.1419070399434,
          "url": "latitude"
        },
        {
          "valueDecimal": -71.28041093915812,
          "url": "longitude"
        }
      ],
      "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/geolocation"
    }],
    "city": "Walpole",
    "line": ["236 Halvorson Mews Suite 21"],
    "state": "MA"
  }],
  "gender": "male",
  "multipleBirthBoolean": false,
  "birthDate": "1960-07-09",
  "meta": {"profile": ["http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-patient"]},
  "deceasedDateTime": "1992-06-21T18:48:35-04:00",
  "name": [{
    "given": [
      "Glenn0",
      "Adalberto916"
    ],
    "use": "official",
    "prefix": ["Mr."],
    "family": "Hermiston71"
  }],
  "telecom": [{
    "system": "phone",
    "use": "home",
    "value": "555-370-8941"
  }],
  "text": {
    "div": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Generated by <a href=\"https://github.com/synthetichealth/synthea\">Synthea<\/a>.Version identifier: master-branch-latest\n .   Person seed: -3481236467670898486  Population seed: 1663786624475<\/div>",
    "status": "generated"
  },
  "communication": [{"language": {
    "coding": [{
      "system": "urn:ietf:bcp:47",
      "code": "en-US",
      "display": "English"
    }],
    "text": "English"
  }}],
  "maritalStatus": {
    "coding": [{
      "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/v3-MaritalStatus",
      "code": "M",
      "display": "M"
    }],
    "text": "M"
  },
  "resourceType": "Patient"
}
```

Modify this message by replacing PATIENT_ID with the id returned when the Patient resource is posted and then post that to https://launch.smarthealthit.org/v/r4/fhir/DiagnosticReport

```
{
  "code": {"coding": [
    {
      "system": "http://loinc.org",
      "code": "34117-2",
      "display": "History and physical note"
    },
    {
      "system": "http://loinc.org",
      "code": "51847-2",
      "display": "Evaluation + Plan note"
    }
  ]},
  "performer": [{
    "display": "Dr. Debbie941 Macejkovic424"
  }],
  "effectiveDateTime": "1978-09-02T17:57:46-04:00",
  "meta": {"profile": ["http://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/StructureDefinition/us-core-diagnosticreport-note"]},
  "subject": {"reference": "https://r4.smarthealthit.org/Patient/PATIENT_ID"},
  "presentedForm": [{
    "data": "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",
    "contentType": "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
  }],
  "category": [{"coding": [
    {
      "system": "http://loinc.org",
      "code": "34117-2",
      "display": "History and physical note"
    },
    {
      "system": "http://loinc.org",
      "code": "51847-2",
      "display": "Evaluation + Plan note"
    }
  ]}],
  "issued": "1978-09-02T17:57:46.296-04:00",
  "resourceType": "DiagnosticReport",
  "status": "final"
}
```

Then try to find the DiagnosticReport using the information (e.g. ID) for the Patient.

Comment: This does look like an issue in that particular server but I don't think anyone is still maintaining it. If there is, you should contact the authors directly

Answer (score 1):

It appears the Patient and DiagnosticReport are now deleted, but you can use the `patient` search parameter. For example, https://r4.smarthealthit.org/DiagnosticReport?patient=3190019b-9001-4e31-a3c4-380b12b8002a currently returns a Bundle of 5 DiagnosticReports.

Comment: This type of query did not work for a Patient and DiagnosticReport created using POST operations.  See EDIT in the original question for details (but it does indeed return results for the example link you provide).